# Load html controls based on JSON in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a form to generate JSON format in bottom we can see. I will select name and control that need to display.How ever from the JSON data which I get from this form. I need to display all the controls in another form or same form. if I select Textbox it should display textbox.

if any one knows to display or render the controls from JSON that will great helpfull.

Here is the code:

```js
var app = angular.module('Example',[]);

app.controller("ExampleController",function ($scope){
$scope.Controls=[];
    $scope.master= {};
    $scope.update = function(user) {
        // Example with 1 argument
        debugger;
        $scope.Controls.push(angular.copy(user));
        $scope.master= $scope.Controls;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body  ng-app="Example">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:60%">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Screen Builder</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="panel panel-default form-left" >
                                <div class="panel-body"  ng-controller="ExampleController">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10" >
                                            <form class="form-horizontal " ng-submit="update(user)">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                            <label >Form Name :</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                                            <input  type="text" ng-model="user.Form">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                            <label >Control :</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-8 text-justify">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label"  value="Label" ng-model="user.Control.type">Label
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label" value="Combo" ng-model="user.Control.type">Combo
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label"  value="Edit Combo" ng-model="user.Control.type">Edit Combo
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label"  value="Combo Grid" ng-model="user.Control.type">Combo Grid
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label"  value="Date" ng-model="user.Control.type">Date
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label"  value="Date Time" ng-model="user.Control.type">Date Time
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label" value="Number" ng-model="user.Control.type">Number
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label" value="Check Box" ng-model="user.Control.type">Check Box
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="Label" value="Option Button" ng-model="user.Control.type">Option Button
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                            <label >Caption :</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                                            <input  type="text" ng-model="user.Control.value">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                                        <input type="submit" style="width: 60px" value="Submit">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                            <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 60%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSsKrteRMnmNXCT4lNOn?p=preview).

It's a simple example that doesn't add all the elements in the main form but it is to show you how it could be done. The idea is to have a dummy form that you append elements to.

JS

```
app.controller("ExampleController",function ($scope, $element){
$scope.Controls=[];
    $scope.master= {};

    var newForm = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#newForm'));
    $scope.update = function(user) {
        // Example with 1 argument
        $scope.Controls.push(angular.copy(user));
        $scope.master= $scope.Controls;
        if (user !== undefined) {
          var element = "";
          if (user.Control.type == "Label") {
            if (user.Control.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
              element = "<div class='col-md-6'><label>" + user.Control.value + "</label></div>";
            }
            else {
              element = "<div class='col-md-6'><label>Label</label></div>";
            }
          }
          else if (user.Control.type == "Check Box") {
            if (user.Control.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
              element = "<div class='col-md-6'><input type='checkbox'>" + user.Control.value + "</input></div>";
            }
            else {
              element = "<div class='col-md-6'><input type='checkbox'></input></div>";
            }
          }
          newForm.append(element)
        }
    };
});
```

Markup

```
                                    <!-- New form -->
                                    <br>
                                    <div>
                                      New Form:
                                      <form id="newForm" class="form-horizontal ">

                                      </form>
                                    </div>
```

Let me know if you want to add the elements by traversing the JSON instead.